# pymongo not outputting data from Mongo collection

Tags: python, mongodb, printing, find, pymongo

I am using pymongo to access a local mongo database. However, I am unable to display the products table data.

I am using below code:

```
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017")
db = client.SCPfondMarket
products = db.products
data = products.find({})

for doc in data:
    print(doc)
```

There is data in the collection. The code does not throw errors, but gives an empty result.
I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, please help.

Comment: What is the output of `products.count_documents({})`?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I was very inattentive and did not notice that all the data was on the test database, which was created when downloading the mongodb client. I was connecting to my newly created one by mistake.